# 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference android

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception, marker

I'm creating an app that display markers on the map. The problem is I'm getting the following error when I run my app:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.flag.app.app.fragment.FragmentMap$1.onMapReady(FragmentMap.java:186)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
```

This is my FragmentMap.class

public class FragmentMap extends Fragment  {

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
public MapView mMapView;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    mMapView =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;
            Log.d("debug", "map ready called");
            LatLng lviv = new LatLng(49.838, 24.029);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lviv, 12));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("debug", "problem");

            }

            List<Marker> markerList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MARKER_LIST);
            for (int i = 0; i < markerList.size(); i++) {
                Marker marker = markerList.get(i);
                Location location = marker.getLocation();
                clusterManager.setItems(markerList);
            }
        }

    });

    return rootView;
}
```

And this is my database screen:
[image: database]

Comment: I think is your markerList var they null when you try too get it size they throw this exception. `List<Marker> markerList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MARKER_LIST);` Check if return null.

Comment: why are you using `MapView` instead of `SupportMapFrament`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue because the value of `markerList` is `NULL`

You should not using this way:

```
List<Marker> markerList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MARKER_LIST);
```

Because the purpose of fragment is re-use.

You should create a constructor for this fragment and pass anything you want like below:

```
 public static MapFragment newInstance(List<Marker> markers) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_MARKER_LIST", markers);
        mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return mapFragment;
    }
```

And please **MAKE SURE** `Marker` already implement `Parcelable`

Hope this helps